# [System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection], OTF Fonts, Windows 7/PS2.0

Tags: powershell, fonts

This works fine in Windows 10

```
$fontFilePath = '\\px\Rollouts\Misc\Fonts\Myriad Pro\MyriadPro-Cond.otf'
$fontCollection = New-Object System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection
$fontCollection.AddFontFile($fontFilePath)
```

but in Windows 7/PS2 I get `Exception calling "AddFontFile" with "1" argument(s): "File not found."`. But a TTF font works fine. So I am thinking that OpenType fonts aren't supported in `[System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection]` in PS2.0?

Comment: It may not be, but I have not v2 systems to validate. Any reason why you still on PSv2? MS has recommended getting off that for a long while now, for a number of reasons. Upgrade to v5x at a minimum, well, if your org allows you to.

Comment: Indeed, the next major version of my utility will require 5.1, but my market is architects and sadly some of them are still in 2.0. Honestly not many, but since everything else in my utility works in 2.0, I was hoping to maintain that for this next minor build. I think I will by going back to the old way of installing fonts for all versions before the Windows 10 build where Microsoft screwed everything up, and only use the new approach where needed. But that does add some complexity. :(

Comment: Feeling your pain...